# Segmentation fault(core dumped). No compiling error. searched the Forum

Tags: c

im learning C and i can't find any solution to my problem, so i turn to you guys for your expertice. 
I can compile and run my code, but after i have entered all the variables the program gives me Segmentation fault (core dumped) 
Im running Geany as editor and gcc as compiler on Ubuntu 14.04.

Ps.My english is not the best.

Heres my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
int inkomst;
int hyra;
int el;
int vatten;
int tele;
int forsakring;
int mat;
int klader;
int lan;
int transport;
int ovrigt;
int summa;
} base;

void budgetBase();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
budgetBase();
return 0;}

void budgetBase(base c){
printf("BudgetBase\n\n");

printf("Monthly income: ");
scanf("%d", &c.inkomst);
printf("\nRent: ");
scanf("%d", &c.hyra);
printf("\nElectric bill: ");
scanf("%d", &c.el);
printf("\nWater bill: ");
scanf("%d", &c.vatten);
printf("\nTele/data bill: ");
scanf("%d", &c.tele);
printf("\nInsurance bill: ");
scanf("%d", &c.forsakring);
printf("\nFood bill: ");
scanf("%d", &c.mat);
printf("\nClothing: ");
scanf("%d", &c.klader);
printf("\nMorgage: ");
scanf("%d", &c.lan);
printf("\nTransport: ");
scanf("%d", &c.transport);
printf("\nOther expenses: ");
scanf("%d", &c.ovrigt);

    int sum = c.inkomst - c.hyra - c.el 
        - c.vatten - c.tele - c.forsakring 
        - c.mat - c.klader - c.lan - c.transport - c.ovrigt;

printf("\n\nSum: %d",sum);

return;}
```

I know it looks nice so please be nice. :)

Comment: Can you paste some of the errors or output?

Comment: for several reasons, do not typedef struct definitions

Comment: the argc and argv[] parameters for main are not used.  the compiler will raise to warnings.  fix that by using the 'int main(void); statement for the main declaration.

Comment: please indent the code.  suggest indent 4 spaces after each opening brace '{' and un-indent 4 spaces before each closing brace '}'.  that makes the code much more human readable.  For readability, please place braces on separate lines rather than mixed into the code.

Comment: when using scanf() and similar functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the input/conversion operation was successful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void budgetBase(base c){
```

should be

```
void budgetBase(){
  base c
  /*Rest of the code*/
```

because you call

```
budgetBase();
```

without any arguments. This should match the function signature.

BTW, the `return;` at the end of the function `budgetBase()` is not needed.

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved it! It is not easy being a noob like me. :)